# Forward file from apache camel to Spring MVC REST controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-camel, cxf, esb

I am using apache-servicemix-4.5.3 with camel routing engine. I want to pass uploaded file to another web application deployed on tomcat 8 with Spring 3 MVC. In simple example:

I have:

```
<cxf:rsServer id="server" address="http://0.0.0.0:9001/">

    <cxf:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="SampleService" />
    </cxf:serviceBeans>

</cxf:rsServer>

<route>
        <from uri="cxfrs://bean://server" />

        <removeHeaders pattern="CamelHttp*"/>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
            <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="ref:someEndpoint" />
</route>
```

Service:

```
@Path("/example")
public interface InvoiceService {
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Result2<Integer> upload(Attachment input) ;
```

On endpoint there is spring REST controller, let it be:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class SomeController{
     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload")
     @ResponseBody
     public Result upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest req){
      //...
     }
```

I have no problem with uploading file to one of the servers, I have problem with forwarding file from ESB (apache-servicemix) to web app deployed on Tomcat.

#### Update

The exact problem is exception occuring probably while sending request to endpoint:

```
No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment@c421de12] of type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList on: Message: [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment@c421de12]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment@c421de12]
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem, is it sending or receiving? 
http://camel.apache.org/http.html

Comment: Sorry for imprecise description, I updated my question.